# Powershell - Difference results between "string" -split and "string".split() without loosing separator

Tags: string, powershell, split

I'm trying to split sentences from string. I found this on Stack Overflow:

```
$stringToExtract = "sentence a. sentence b. sentence c. last phrase"
$mySentences = $stringToExtract -split "(?<=\.)"
$mySentences
sentence a.
 sentence b.
 sentence c.
 last phrase
```

But...

```
$stringToExtract = "sentence a. sentence b. sentence c. last phrase"
$mySentences = $stringToExtract.split("(?<=\.)")
$mySentences
sentence a
 sentence b
 sentence c
 last phrase
```

... different results.

I want to use the code
`$mySentences = $stringToExtract.split("(?<=\.)")`. Somebody please tell me know what was wrong with the thing.
Thanks.

Comment: `-split` is an operator that uses regex. `(?<=\.)` is a regex positive lookbehind for the `.` character. It consumes no characters, which is why the `.` remains after splitting.  In the `.split()` method, which does not use regex, just treats all of those characters as characters to split by. Since `.` is the only one in your strings, it’s the only one that splits.

Comment: `-split` and other operators like `-match` and `-replace` use regex while `.match` `.replace` and `.split` do not use regex.

Comment: Also, if you are happy with the `.split()` method results, just reduce it to `.split('.')` for conciseness.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm very much appreciated.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I want to keep the dot at the end of sentences if they are really a sentence. I'm extracting sentences from string by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-split` is an operator that uses regex. `(?<=\.)` is a regex positive lookbehind for the `.` character. It matches the position where there is a `.` character directly behind it. But since it consumes no characters, none of the characters are removed after the split including the `.`.

The `String.Split()` method, which does not use regex, treats all of those characters as a character array to split by. So that means it would split at `(`,`?`,`<`,`=`,`\`,`.`, and `)`. Since `.` is the only one that ever matches in your strings, it's the only one that splits. Since `String.Split()` does consume characters, your split characters are removed.

To get the desired result, I suggest sticking with `-split`. There is no reason not to use it.

```
$stringToExtract = "sentence a. sentence b. sentence c. last phrase"
$mySentences = $stringToExtract -split "(?<=\.)"
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Regex.Split()` method to get the same effect if using a method is more aesthetically pleasing.

```
$mySentences = [regex]::Split($stringToExtract,'(?<=\.)')
```

Comment: Hey. Could you help me build a regular expression to extract this sentence part from the line: `"From a starry sky a wide view descends to a magnificent castle with a ..."` There is the `n dot`: one, two, `...` or `........` at the end and I want to include them all. I have try `$mySentences = [regex]::Split($stringToExtract,'(?<=(\.+?)')` but no success.